# Ubuntu terminates all Internet connections

Tags: wireless, internet, router

I recently installed Ubuntu 17.04 in my laptop computer. However, once I try to connect to the internet, the connection breaks down on all devices and I am not able to reconnect. However, I can connect to the internet of I create a hotspot on my mobile phone.

WiFi works fine on my phone until I start the computer. Then the connection terminates on all devices.

Thanks,

Bob

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device. Please open a terminal and run and post the result of: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`